# Do I need to use a new WordPress.com account for each Jetpack installation

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, plugin-jetpack

I manage lots of WordPress.org installations for different clients. Typically they do not manage the posts or pages themselves, preferring to stay out of things and let me do it.

JetPack functionality is great, but obviously you need to sign into a WordPress.com account within the installation to access it.

My question is - is it recommended to create new WordPress.com accounts for each client, or shall I just sign in to mine on each installation? What are the pros / cons e.g. are the WP-stats merged (this would obviously be bad)?

Many thanks

Comment: I'd like to ask this question again in 2018. Is there any update on best practices for managing client sites? Is it better to use a single WordPress.com account for all sites, or a new one for each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you only need it to activate. I use it on 4 sites with same account.

Comment: Cool, so does it save anything about the particular installation to the WordPress.com account? Or are stats saved independently to each blog. Just trying to understand whether there are any disadvantages or using my account on every installation.

Comment: Well as far as I know, wordpress.com itself doesnt saves anything. I checked it out on my wordpress.com account and found nothing what so ever relating to my Jet Pack Site Stats. Hope this info helps.

Comment: It actually does save the linked accounts. If you login to your WordPress.com account and go to Dashboard > My Blogs You should see "Linked Blogs" towards the bottom of the page. It gives you the option to Hide/Show the blog in your dashboard. The stats however are install independent.

Answer (score 3):

You only need one account, however I often create a new account for client work. WordPress.com allow accounts without blogs on WP.com which is normally what I do if someone else may possibly need access to the account.